# Encode Response in REST service

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson, jax-rs

I use class `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` in my service method:

```
@GET
@Path("/object/{id}")    
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response findObject(@Context HttpHeaders headers,
                                 @PathParam("id") String objectId) {
    Object object = getObject(objectId);
    return createResponse(object, headers);
}

private Response createResponse(Object object, HttpHeaders headers) {
    Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response
            .ok()
            .entity(object)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .build();
}
```

And instance of `Response` contents hierarchy of my system which is contained in the instance `object`. This's object with all its children and their properties. And I want encoding values of properties in `object`. I need to give in response percent-encoding symbols instead of space in names for example. I need encoding whole my response including all fields. According to the UTF-8 encoding. For example, instead of value of some field `'His name: John'` I need have `'His20%name%3A20%John'` in my response. And similarly for all fields without exception in the whole hierarchy.

I didn't find anything better than how each field was handled manually using the method [URLEncoder.encode(String s, String enc)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

```
fieldValue = URLEncoder.encode(fieldValue, "UTF-8");
```

But in this case I need to manually go through all the fields that are in all the objects of my hierarchy coming in response. Maybe there is a more standard and correct way to do this?

And some fields are not string and have for example type BigDecimal. They can contain delimiters. How do I process them? Is there any way to encode the entire object response before return?

Comment: You want to store encoded data in json ?

Comment: Yes, I use JSON format for response.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate fields/getter for encoded properties. In this way, the original values will be kept intact. You can also rely on reflection to fetch all fields and do it which will be messier than this.

```
class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String encodedName;

    public String getEncodedName(){
        return URLEncoder.encode(this.firstName, "UTF-8”)+URLEncoder.encode(this.lastName, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Comment: I encode each property separately too. But I do not really like this approach. In your case I need change my model and violate responsibility principle. I would like to know if anyone knows something more elegant and simple way with specific handling of response. My hierarchy is really very large.